# Null Pointer Exception In Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am getting NullPointerException while Starting One Fragment From other Fragment. I am trying to call a method in the second Fragment after Starting the Fragment dynamically.

Here is my logcat:

```
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at com.exercise.FragmentTest.MyFragment3.setImage(MyFragment3.java:22)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at com.exercise.FragmentTest.FragmentTestActivity$1.onClick(FragmentTestActivity.java:48)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-20 09:58:31.907: E/AndroidRuntime(2585):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And My Main Activity code:

```
public class FragmentTestActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    Fragment fragment;
    Button btnFragment1, btnFragment2, btnFragment3;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnFragment1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.displayfragment1);
        btnFragment2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.displayfragment2);
        btnFragment3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.displayfragment3);

       // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity 
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //add a fragment 
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        btnFragment1.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);
        btnFragment2.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);
        btnFragment3.setOnClickListener(btnFragmentOnClickListener);
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnFragmentOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(v == btnFragment3){
                MyFragment3 newfragment = new MyFragment3();

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack
                transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newfragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
                            newfragment.setImage();
                return;

            }


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment newFragment = null;

            // Create new fragment
            if(v == btnFragment1){
                newFragment = new MyFragment();
            }
                else if(v == btnFragment2){
                    newFragment = new MyFragment2();
                }


            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

            // Create new transaction

        }};

}
```

And My Fragment3 class is:

```
public class MyFragment3 extends Fragment {
    ImageView iv;
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout3, container, false);
      iv = (ImageView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.image); 

      return myFragmentView;
     }
     public void setImage(){
         iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.penguins);
     }
}
```

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: is R.id.image declared inside fragmentlayout3 ?

Comment: @blackbelt, yes, i need to display the dynamic image in the fragment based on Main Activity button click..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your error is happening here:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
newfragment.setImage();
```

and it's happening because the variable `iv` is still `null`.

you have to wait until after the Fragment is shown (inflated) in order to access the Views that were inflated into it.

for more, try reading about the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

> onCreateView() 
>   The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

a very good way of creating this will be using the `setArgs` method and passing a `Bundle` with the information about your image.

try using this code:

```
public MyFragment3 extends Fragment {

    public static final IMAGE_RES = "IMAGE_RES";
    private int imageRes;
    private ImageView iv;

    public static MyFragment3 init(int imageRes) {
        MyFragment3 frag = new MyFragment3();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(IMAGE_RES, imageRes);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        return frag;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);

        imageRes = (getArguments() != null)? getArguments().getInt(IMAGE_RES) : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout3, container, false);
         iv = (ImageView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.image); 
         iv.setImageResource(imageRes);

         return myFragmentView;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i call Fragment3() frag = new Fragment(), what happens? won't it create new fragment and the lifecycle methods like, oncreate, oncreateView?

Comment: go to the link attached, you can see exactly what method is called and when. you can't set images to null, and the View is not created until `onCreateView` is called

Comment: yeah.. Thank you.. It works perfect if i have less number of views. But in my case i have to use more than 10 views that are based on Previous Fragment

Comment: you cane create a helper class to take care of this. trust me, this is the correct way to go, it was designed like that, and all the Android sample projects are built like this.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try this. Can you please mail me any example for doing this.. srikanth.gnani@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

```
MyFragment3 newfragment = new MyFragment3();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
newfragment.setImage();
```

You are trying to access imageview which will be created in onCreateView of the fragment. When you call `newfragment.setImage();` your view is not yet created hence you are getting a NPE.

Comment: I have to set the image From the First Fragment itself.. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: try using `setArgs` for passing this type of information to the fragment

Comment: what parameters can i pass in the args? like, i have 10 number of image views, Textviews.. So i think setArgs is not the alternative

Comment: `Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("image", i);
        newfragment.setArguments(args);` In MyFragment3 you can call `getArguments().getInt("image", 0);` to get the passed value to the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way because onCreateView has not been called yet so your `iv` is null.
You can put `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.penguins);` in the `onCreateView()` or maybe in `onAttach()` (I'm not sure about the second one).

Comment: Is there any better way to load the content in fragment3 dynamically from Frag 2?

Comment: You can pass some booleans as arguments which will be indicating what you want to load. For example you can pass bundle with isSetImage boolean and then in onCreateView() depending on this flag you can set your image or not.

Comment: that is fine.. But i have more than 10 view that controlled by the main Activity. And i have some ArrayLists. I am new to Fragments, can u please help me with an example.

Comment: http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial read this article, it should help you understand fragments.

Comment: I read this Document.. In this he is doing only attaching the fragments, replacing.. In My case it is working.. But the problem is only when i try to call a method from Previous Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use **getActivity.findViewById** in Fragment

```
public class MyFragment3 extends Fragment {
    ImageView iv;
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout3, container, false);
      iv = (ImageView)getActivity.findViewById(R.id.image); 

      return myFragmentView;
     }
     public void setImage(){
         iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.penguins);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because I was trying to use the `SwipeRefreshLayout` as the root element of the fragment's layout XML. Once I added the `SwipeRefreshLayout` as a child of the `ConstraintLayout` used by the fragment it started working.