# Fragment B ist created/nested in Fragment A ,is it possible to access Fragment B from Fragment A?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Similiar to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647552/null-pointer-exception-in-fragments) issue, i was trying to access and manipulate a second fragment that was created in the first fragment, before i realized that the nullpointerException is most probably caused by the nonready state of the second fragment. So is this generally not possible and i have to do something like passing a bundle with the data?

That works:

`MyMap mapFragment = new MyMap();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame,mapFragment,"map")
                .commit();`

but this gives me a null reference:

`MyMap mapFragment =  (MyMap)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`

Comment: use `findFragmentByTag("map");`

Comment: Already tried this, gives me a nullPointerException as well..